# How can I deformat string with prices in python?

Tags: python, regex, string, formatting

I got db where one of the field in record in table contain prices in form of string.
String itself is not a big deal - but price is totally unformatted:

```
$12,000.50
$3.50
From $3.50 to $12,000.50
```

what I trying to get is:

```
12000.50
3.50
3.50
```

strip it from all "$" and "," and leave only first digit of two

I made this code and it works for first to examples but fail for last one (sqlite syntax error - obviosly it gives me both digits)

Here is code:

```
for every_line:
           found=re.findall(r"\d.\.?",every_line[9])
           db_cursor.execute("UPDATE MAINTABLE SET Price="+"".join(found)+" WHERE Id="+str(every_line[0]))
db_connection.commit()
```

where every_line[0] is index field and [9] is price field

How can I make it more efficient (with or without regex), simpler  and more universal ?

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `','` with an empty string (`''`) and then apply this simple `regex`:

```
>>> r = re.compile("\$(\d+.\d+)")

>>> r.search(strs.replace(',','')).group(1)
'12000.50'

>>> strs = '$3.50'
>>> r.search(strs.replace(',','')).group(1)
'3.50'

>>> strs = 'From $3.50 to $12,000.50'
>>> r.search(strs.replace(',','')).group(1)
'3.50'
```

Comment: `re.compile()` is excellent for showing invariance in regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is by using `findall`you will retrieve all matching text fragments. But, there is two matching fragment in the last example:

```
>>> re.findall(r"\d.\.?", "From $3.50 tp $12,000.50" )
['3.', '50', '12', '00', '0.', '50']
```

And joining them will not produce something that could be seen as a number:

```
>>> "".join(['3.', '50', '12', '00', '0.', '50'])
'3.5012000.50'
```

---

Assuming all your prices start with `$`and you are only interested in the *first* price, something like that might be better:

```
>>> import re
>>> import string

>>> p = [ "$12,000.50", "$3.50", "From $3.50 tp $12,000.50", "$12,000" ]
>>> [re.search(r"\$(\d+(\.\d+)?)", string.replace(price,",","")).group(0) for price in p]
['$12000.50', '$3.50', '$3.50', '$12000']

>>> [re.search(r"\$(\d+(\.\d+)?)", string.replace(price,",","")).group(1) for price in p]
['12000.50', '3.50', '3.50', '12000']
```

As you noticed, this handle properly prices *without* cents.

Comment: But the answer for the third one should be 3.50 alone